Dimensional analysis of a simple linear regression coefficient
I was asking ChatGPT about the intuition behind the beta coefficient and, after some back and forth, it came with an interesting response. It said that we can use dimensional analysis to improve our understanding of the coefficient. Its elaboration was the following:


According to the LLM, this is why we interpret the coefficient as a the (beta) units of Y given a unit change of X.
Is this application of dimensional analysis correct?

The answer is yes.

The dimensional analysis in the OP seem OK to me.
The formula for $\beta_1$ is obtained by taking the ratio of the covariance of $x$ and $y$ to the variance of $x$. Examining the units of each term, we get:

In the numerator, $\sum (x_i - \bar{x})(y_i - \bar{y})$, we find units of $[ \text{units of } x ] \times [ \text{units of } y ]$.
In the denominator, $\sum (x_i - \bar{x})^2$, we find units of $[ \text{units of } x ]^2$.

Division then yields
$$\text{Units of } \beta_1 = \frac{[ \text{units of } x ] \times [ \text{units of } y ]}{[ \text{units of } x ]^2} = \frac{[ \text{units of } y ]}{[ \text{units of } x ]}
$$
, which confirms that $\beta_1$ has units of $[ \text{units of } y ] / [ \text{units of }x]$. This dimensional interpretation agrees with the typical interpretation of $\beta_1$: it represents the change in $y$ (in its units) for a one-unit change in $x$.
